# Is there a function or class in ActiveJDBC that will get MySQL table column names? (String)

Tags: mysql, activejdbc, javalite

How to get table column names in MySQL using activejdbc?

Comment: Give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take some time to explore the JavaDoc: [Model.html#attributeNames](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.html#attributeNames--)

Find JavaDoc links on the site: http://javalite.io/javadoc

Comment: Thanks, finally got it. :)

Comment: I cant not enough reputation :(